# How to get pointers to concatenated string or default type like bool?

Tags: go

I'm new to golang and am struggling to wrap my head around how to get a pointer to a concatenated string without a helper function, and what the reasoning behind that is. The same goes for type bool.

For example, I cannot do either of the below:

```
myBool := &true
myString := &string("foo" + someVar + "bar")
```

As a quick/dirty workaround I wrote helper functions that accept a bool or a string and return a pointer.

For example:

```
func GetBoolPointer(i bool) *bool {
    return &i
}
```

It's especially odd to me because I can directly get a pointer for other types, like `myVar := &SomeDefinedType`.

Comment: First create a var for the string then take the address var myString = "hi"; var ps *string = &myString

Comment: If this question is reference to using the AWS SDK (as are some previous questions on this topic), then use the the [AWS Value and Pointer Conversion Utilities](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws#hdr-Value_and_Pointer_Conversion_Utilities).

Comment: Being unable to take the address of a literal `true` is as odd as being unable to take the address of a literal `17`: Not at all. Only variables have addresses. Duplicate.

Comment: @CeriseLimón - no, it's not referencing the AWS SDK, though interestingly enough, it is another cloud providers API that does not have conversion utilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only get the address of an addressable value:

https://golang.org/ref/spec#Address_operators

Literals are not addressable. You need to have a variable holding that value:

```
t:=true
myBool:=&t
```

Comment: Thank you, this makes complete sense.